# Programmatically to compress the video without FFMPEG in Android

Tags: android, video, compression

Is it possible to programmatically compress video using standard functions, such as in the IOS AVAssetExportSession, not using FFMPEG

Comment: Any reason why you dont want to use FFMPEG?

Comment: I understand need to use NDK, which is undesirable for the project. I just have not seen that it was possible to use FFMPEG without NDK. If I'm wrong - correct me and tell me how?

Comment: Yes I think you are right, need NDK to use it.

Comment: What type of video do you want to encode? If you can possibly use hardware acceleration features on Android devices, that will certainly be preferable to encoding purely in software using FFmpeg.

Comment: I need from the MP4 video file size of 1 GB compress and transfer it, for example by e-mail. But not zipping, namely compress

Comment: Hi, did you found a solution for your problem? Thanks.

Comment: No, yet there is no solution to this question

Comment: Hi . did u find any solution ??

Comment: Unfortunately no, had to use FFMPEG

Comment: Hi, did u find any solution for compress video?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683960/android-video-encoding-with-fr-and-resolution-manipulation/23815402#23815402..... use this i was tried it, its working fine little bit time taking.